# KoLite knockout.command has incorrect context with inherited class

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript, kolite

When a subclass viewmodel is bound to a View, that overrides a method in a base class in inherits from, "[knockout.command](https://github.com/CodeSeven/KoLite)" seems to be calling the base method instead of the child overridden method.

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chedeatg/) in javascript, although I'm using typescript.

Note a plain old click binding alerts "child action" while the knockout.command alerts "base action".  How can I make this correctly call the overridden child method?

Typescript:

```
class BaseVm {

    public commandAction: any;

    constructor() {
        this.commandAction = ko.asyncCommand({ execute: this.action, canExecute: (isExecuting) => true });
    } 
    public clickAction = () => {
        this.action(null, null, null);
    }
    public action = (val, event, complete) => {
        alert("base action");
    }
}

class ChildVm extends BaseVm {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    public action = (loc, event, complete) => {
        alert("child action");
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ChildVm());
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TEST</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/CodeSeven/KoLite/master/knockout.command.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <button data-bind="command: { click: $root.commandAction }">COMMAND</button>
    <button data-bind="click: $root.clickAction">CLICK</button>
    <script>
        ko.applyBindings(new ChildVm());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't context, it's that base class constructors run before derived class constructors, and it's the derived class constructor where `action` gets overwritten by the derived class implementation.

When this line of code runs, `this.action` still refers to the base class implementation, and the value is captured at that moment.

```
constructor() {
    this.commandAction = ko.asyncCommand({ execute: this.action, canExecute: (isExecuting) => true });
}
```

You can instead write this to dynamically get the value of `this.action`:

```
constructor() {
    this.commandAction = ko.asyncCommand({ execute: (a, b, c) => this.action(a, b, c), canExecute: (isExecuting) => true });
}
```

Comment: ok, how does essentially using _this instead fix it? Doesn't "this" == "_this" in the constructor anyways?

Comment: `this === _this` when the constructor runs, but *not in the function bodies*